# offline use of the google earth plugin

Tags: offline, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a use case that requires offline access to google earth.  I know that google earth enterprise offers a disconnected product, however we may not have access to that product and/or google earth enterprise is prohibitively expensive at $25K for a dev license.

I would prefer to use the google earth plugin since I am building an application and would like to use the JS api.  Is it possible to host the google earth plugin on my own disconnected server?  We would use google earth connected to a standalone offline WMS server for access to imagery.

said another way, can I host the plugin and corresponding javascript on my own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to cache Google Earth with a proxy server but I couldn't. 
Furthermore I think the api is validated every time it loads against Google Servers and doesn't allow offline use

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if i understand well your problem but i can explain you waht I'm currently working on.

Im my current application with google earth plugin js api, I'm able to start the plugin even if offline. But one requirement is to have cached data.
If you have cached data and if you start the plugin offline, then zooming to a level with higher resolution that the one you have in your cached data will have no effect (imagery will not be update to higher resolution)

but depending on what you really need, yes , you can start the plugin offline

This is not really answering your original question but if you are interested, just tell me :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's some monthes now since I have worked with this.
I'll try to explain with what i can remember :-)

in the html where i have my plug-in, i have removed:
"script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">

but i have saved locally this jsapi.js file. I also saved locally loader_1-008.js

then, im my code (c++, Qt) I'm using evaluateJavaScript(Qstring source) twice
where source is the text read from my 2 .js files
These 2 evaluateJavaScript calls need to be done before loading my html (the one with the plugin) 
in my QWebView

I can not remmeber much more but I hope this can start to help you